# using DART - cant accsess json object fields and add to google maps Marker object

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

(1) my app needs to get coordinates from an api call

(3) I printed the response and this is what it gave me

```
{
  "nhits": 139,
  "parameters": {
    "dataset": [
      "geonames-postal-code@public"
    ],
    "rows": 10,
    "start": 0,
    "facet": [
      "country_code",
      "admin_name1",
      "admin_code1",
      "admin_name2"
    ],
    "format": "json",
    "timezone": "UTC"
  },
  "records": [
    {
      "datasetid": "geonames-postal-code@public",
      "recordid": "b26080136ddb5feb5771b7b69953305f9d7dfeef",
      "fields": {
        "postal_code": "D08",
        "admin_name1": "Leinster",
        "place_name": "Dublin 8",
        "country_code": "IE",
        "coordinates": [
          53.3346,
          -6.2733
        ],
        "admin_code1": "L",
        "latitude": 53.3346,
        "longitude": -6.2733
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -6.2733,
          53.3346
        ]
      },
      "record_timestamp": "2022-07-09T23:00:01.653Z"
    },
    {
      "datasetid": "geonames-postal-code@public",
      "recordid": "9e697cace21428468c9e4e9bc44f2b1f8bf2b860",
      "fields": {
        "postal_code": "N37",
        "admin_name1": "Leinster",
        "place_name": "Athlone",
        "country_code": "IE",
        "coordinates": [
          53.4228,
          -7.9372
        ],
        "admin_code1": "L",
        "latitude": 53.4228,
        "accuracy": 4,
        "longitude": -7.9372
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -7.9372,
          53.4228
        ]
      },
      "record_timestamp": "2022-07-09T23:00:01.653Z"
    },
    {
      "datasetid": "geonames-postal-code@public",
      "recordid": "187f59cc0a419aa52403903bf6424239e0d4b58c",
      "fields": {
        "postal_code": "P56",
        "admin_name1": "Munster",
        "place_name": "Charleville",
        "country_code": "IE",
        "coordinates": [
          52.35,
          -8.6833
        ],
        "admin_code1": "M",
        "latitude": 52.35,
        "accuracy": 4,
        "longitude": -8.6833
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -8.6833,
          52.35
        ]
      },
      "record_timestamp": "2022-07-09T23:00:01.653Z"
    },
    {
      "datasetid": "geonames-postal-code@public",
      "recordid": "51c501dd3a996cc1a184ae051208edddc89ae3f5",
      "fields": {
        "postal_code": "D11",
        "admin_name1": "Leinster",
        "place_name": "Dublin 11",
        "country_code": "IE",
        "coordinates": [
          53.3899,
          -6.293
        ],
        "admin_code1": "L",
        "latitude": 53.3899,
        "longitude": -6.293
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -6.293,
          53.3899
        ]
      },
      "record_timestamp": "2022-07-09T23:00:01.653Z"
    },
    {
      "datasetid": "geonames-postal-code@public",
      "recordid": "d51c23cd3ad68b02c62db072352efae58badecb7",
      "fields": {
        "postal_code": "R93",
        "admin_name1": "Leinster",
        "place_name": "Carlow",
        "country_code": "IE",
        "coordinates": [
          52.8408,
          -6.9261
        ],
        "admin_code1": "L",
        "latitude": 52.8408,
        "accuracy": 4,
        "longitude": -6.9261
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -6.9261,
          52.8408
        ]
      },
      "record_timestamp": "2022-07-09T23:00:01.653Z"
    },
    {
      "datasetid": "geonames-postal-code@public",
      "recordid": "30f01b294f53ec478dc10bd5b8ea8a9d97c7283a",
      "fields": {
        "postal_code": "P72",
        "admin_name1": "Munster",
        "place_name": "Bandon",
        "country_code": "IE",
        "coordinates": [
          51.7469,
          -8.7425
        ],
        "admin_code1": "M",
        "latitude": 51.7469,
        "accuracy": 4,
        "longitude": -8.7425
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -8.7425,
          51.7469
        ]
      },
      "record_timestamp": "2022-07-09T23:00:01.653Z"
    },
    {
      "datasetid": "geonames-postal-code@public",
      "recordid": "9ef1246a9613898a0b53610cecc87bc7ad470cd0",
      "fields": {
        "postal_code": "T12",
        "admin_name1": "Munster",
        "place_name": "Cork city southside",
        "country_code": "IE",
        "coordinates": [
          51.8728,
          -8.4902
        ],
        "admin_code1": "M",
        "latitude": 51.8728,
        "longitude": -8.4902
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -8.4902,
          51.8728
        ]
      },
      "record_timestamp": "2022-07-09T23:00:01.653Z"
    },
    {
      "datasetid": "geonames-postal-code@public",
      "recordid": "f97dbc8d75902eed5d362970e108c95ccc193e21",
      "fields": {
        "postal_code": "F92",
        "admin_name1": "Ulster",
        "place_name": "Letterkenny",
        "country_code": "IE",
        "coordinates": [
          54.95,
          -7.7333
        ],
        "admin_code1": "U",
        "latitude": 54.95,
        "accuracy": 4,
        "longitude": -7.7333
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -7.7333,
          54.95
        ]
      },
      "record_timestamp": "2022-07-09T23:00:01.653Z"
    },
    {
      "datasetid": "geonames-postal-code@public",
      "recordid": "b676e5a6ee40c1ff1489917ed028474d1e2810d8",
      "fields": {
        "postal_code": "N41",
        "admin_name1": "Connacht",
        "place_name": "Carrick On Shannon",
        "country_code": "IE",
        "coordinates": [
          53.9469,
          -8.09
        ],
        "admin_code1": "C",
        "latitude": 53.9469,
        "accuracy": 4,
        "longitude": -8.09
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -8.09,
          53.9469
        ]
      },
      "record_timestamp": "2022-07-09T23:00:01.653Z"
    },
    {
      "datasetid": "geonames-postal-code@public",
      "recordid": "a5caf8ece3a46fb2d7ba84219acbb4cea918179b",
      "fields": {
        "postal_code": "P14",
        "admin_name1": "Leinster",
        "place_name": "Crookstown",
        "country_code": "IE",
        "coordinates": [
          53.0153,
          -6.8106
        ],
        "admin_code1": "L",
        "latitude": 53.0153,
        "accuracy": 4,
        "longitude": -6.8106
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -6.8106,
          53.0153
        ]
      },
      "record_timestamp": "2022-07-09T23:00:01.653Z"
    }
  ],
  "facet_groups": [
    {
      "name": "country_code",
      "facets": [
        {
          "name": "IE",
          "count": 139,
          "state": "refined",
          "path": "IE"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "admin_name1",
      "facets": [
        {
          "name": "Leinster",
          "count": 68,
          "state": "displayed",
          "path": "Leinster"
        },
        {
          "name": "Munster",
          "count": 43,
          "state": "displayed",
          "path": "Munster"
        },
        {
          "name": "Connacht",
          "count": 18,
          "state": "displayed",
          "path": "Connacht"
        },
        {
          "name": "Ulster",
          "count": 10,
          "state": "displayed",
          "path": "Ulster"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "admin_code1",
      "facets": [
        {
          "name": "L",
          "count": 68,
          "state": "displayed",
          "path": "L"
        },
        {
          "name": "M",
          "count": 43,
          "state": "displayed",
          "path": "M"
        },
        {
          "name": "C",
          "count": 18,
          "state": "displayed",
          "path": "C"
        },
        {
          "name": "U",
          "count": 10,
          "state": "displayed",
          "path": "U"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

(2) I use `jsonDecode()` on the `response.body`

(3)then i try to accsess the Fields array and loop through to get each `postal_code` and each `longitude` and each `latitude`

(4) here is my code. the `getCountry()` method is not adding the marker objects to the set
and when i print the post_Code, longitude and latitude they are empty

(5) printing the list length gives me null as well in the loop

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class MapPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapPageState createState() => _MapPageState();
}

double? cLat = 53.390;
double? cLong = -6.293;

class _MapPageState extends State<MapPage> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  static final CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(53.3346, -6.2733),
    zoom: 15.4746,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      //waits for stream to have data in it befor building the widget
      future: getCountry(cLong, cLat),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data == null) {
          return Scaffold(body: Text("it NO works"));
        } else {
          return Scaffold(body: Text("it  work"));
        }

        //returns the map
      },
    );
  }

  Widget getBody(Set<Marker> list) {
    return GoogleMap(
      //this gets the long and lat of the camera position and then returns a country code corisponding to that
      onCameraMove: (object) => {
        setState(() {
          cLat = object.target.latitude;
          cLong = object.target.longitude;
        })
      },
      markers: list,
      mapType: MapType.normal,
      buildingsEnabled: false,
      myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
      initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
        _controller.complete(controller);
      },
    );
  }
}

//get country code
Future<Set<Marker>> getCountry(double? long, double? lat) async {
  double lat1;
  double long1;
  lat1 = lat!;
  long1 = long!;
  String code = "";
  Set<Marker> list = {};

  //code taken from geocoding pub dev page
  List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(lat1, long1);
  //get first entry in the list of placemarkers
  Placemark place = placemarks[0];

  var postCodesResponse = await http.get(Uri.parse(
      'https://data.opendatasoft.com/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=geonames-postal-code%40public&q=&facet=country_code&facet=admin_name1&facet=admin_code1&facet=admin_name2&refine.country_code=${place.isoCountryCode!}'));

  // print("lol" + postCodesResponse.body);
  var postCodesJson = jsonDecode(postCodesResponse.body);
  // var name = postCodesJson['records']["fields"][1]["postal_code"];
  // var lat2 = postCodesJson['records']["fields"][1]["latitude"];
  // var long2 = postCodesJson['records']["fields"][1]["longitude"];
  // print(name);
  // print(lat2);
  ///print(long2);

  if (code != place.isoCountryCode!) {
    for (var i in postCodesJson['records']) {
      Marker marker = Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(i["fields"]["postal_code"]),
          position: LatLng(i["fields"]["latitude"], i["fields"]["longitude"]));
      list.add(marker);
      print(list.length);
    }
    code = place.isoCountryCode!;
    return list;
  }

  return list;
}
```

any suggestions at all would be appreciated :)
Thank You.

Comment: Can you _print_ `lat1` and `long1` right before `return list;` and show the output?

Comment: lat1 and long1 both return the latitude and longitude provided to the function. i use these variables to determine the address then to determine the ISO code. Then i concatnate the isocode to the URI in this case the ISO code is IE for ireland, it then returns the json data for ireland. my problem seems to be with the postCodesJson var

Comment: Does `print(jsonDecode(postCodesResponse.body))` show something too?

Comment: yes 
when i print that after i get the response it prints the json

Comment: problem seems to be when parsing the json from the `postCodeJson` object in these lines
` for (var i in postCodesJson['records']) {
      Marker marker = Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(i["fields"]["postal_code"]),
          position: LatLng(i["fields"]["latitude"], i["fields"]["longitude"]));
      list.add(marker);
      print(list.length);
    }`

Comment: i want to loop through `records` array and get the `post_code` , `longitude`, `latitude` fields for each entry

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code on an Android emulator by wrapping the MapPage() with a Scaffold in an Material App etc. (I had to adjust the minSdkVersion though)
When compiling and running the code the Text("it work") was shown, and I couldn't replicate your error.
Debugging and looking at each line I would say, each does what it's supposed to do.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: MapPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MapPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapPageState createState() => _MapPageState();
}

double? cLat = 53.390;
double? cLong = -6.293;

class _MapPageState extends State<MapPage> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  static final CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(53.3346, -6.2733),
    zoom: 15.4746,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      //waits for stream to have data in it befor building the widget
      future: getCountry(cLong, cLat),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data == null) {
          return Scaffold(body: Text("it NO works"));
        } else {
          return Scaffold(body: Text("it  work"));
        }

        //returns the map
      },
    );
  }

  Widget getBody(Set<Marker> list) {
    return GoogleMap(
      //this gets the long and lat of the camera position and then returns a country code corisponding to that
      onCameraMove: (object) => {
        setState(() {
          cLat = object.target.latitude;
          cLong = object.target.longitude;
        })
      },
      markers: list,
      mapType: MapType.normal,
      buildingsEnabled: false,
      myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
      initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
        _controller.complete(controller);
      },
    );
  }
}

//get country code
Future<Set<Marker>> getCountry(double? long, double? lat) async {
  double lat1;
  double long1;
  lat1 = lat!;
  long1 = long!;
  String code = "";
  Set<Marker> list = {};

  //code taken from geocoding pub dev page
  List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(lat1, long1);
  //get first entry in the list of placemarkers
  Placemark place = placemarks[0];

  var postCodesResponse = await http.get(Uri.parse(
      'https://data.opendatasoft.com/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=geonames-postal-code%40public&q=&facet=country_code&facet=admin_name1&facet=admin_code1&facet=admin_name2&refine.country_code=${place.isoCountryCode!}'));

  // print("lol" + postCodesResponse.body);
  var postCodesJson = jsonDecode(postCodesResponse.body);
  // var name = postCodesJson['records']["fields"][1]["postal_code"];
  // var lat2 = postCodesJson['records']["fields"][1]["latitude"];
  // var long2 = postCodesJson['records']["fields"][1]["longitude"];
  // print(name);
  // print(lat2);
  ///print(long2);

  if (code != place.isoCountryCode!) {
    for (var i in postCodesJson['records']) {
      Marker marker = Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(i["fields"]["postal_code"]),
          position: LatLng(i["fields"]["latitude"], i["fields"]["longitude"]));
      list.add(marker);
      print(list.length);
    }
    code = place.isoCountryCode!;
    return list;
  }

  return list;
}
```

Comment: did the markers get added to the list. by running `print(list.length)` in the loop did you get zero for each iteration?

Comment: the output was counting from 1 to 10